# $f|_Z(A)=f(A)\cap f(Z)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let be $f:X\rightarrow Y$ a function and let be $Z\subseteq X$: so if we consider the restriction $f|_Z$  of $f$ to $Z$ is it $f|_Z(A)=f(A)\cap f(Z)$, for any $A\subseteq X$?

Comment: $f\lvert_Z(A)$ is not well defined if $A$ is not a subset of $Z$. What you need to consider is $f\lvert_Z (A\cap Z)$ or from the start demand $A\subseteq Z$. In this case you do get $f\lvert_Z (A \cap Z ) = f(A \cap Z) \cap f(Z) = f(A)\cap f(Z)$.

Comment: As an example to the main point of the previous comment, consider $f: \Bbb Q\to \Bbb N$ with $f(x) = p$ where $x=p/q$ with $gcd(p, q)=1, p≥0$. Here it is clear that there is no way for $f(\pi)$ to make sense.

Comment: @s.harp I agree with your comment that $f|_Z(A)$  is not well-defined. But it is *not* true that $f|_Z(A\cap Z) = f(A)\cap f(Z)$. Set-theoretic image does not play well with intersection. See my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right, I wasn't being very careful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\colon X\to Y$ is a function, the set theoretic image $g(A)$ only makes sense when $A$ is a subset of the domain of $g$, so we should have $A\subseteq X$.

Now when you write $f|_Z(A)$ for arbitrary $A\subseteq X$, this is problematic, because the domain of $f|_Z$ is $Z$, and we may not have $A\subseteq Z$. Presumably by $f|_Z(A)$ you mean $f|_Z(Z\cap A)$.

Now note that $f|_Z(Z\cap A)$ is the same as $f(Z\cap A)$, so your question comes down to whether $f(Z\cap A) = f(Z)\cap f(A)$ for arbitrary $Z\subseteq X$ and $A\subseteq X$.

This is *not* true. For example, suppose $X = \{1,2\}$ and $Y = \{0\}$ and $f\colon X\to Y$ is the unique function: $f(1) = 0$ and $f(2) = 0$. Let $Z = \{1\}$ and $A = \{2\}$. Then $f(Z\cap A) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, but $f(Z)\cap f(A) = \{0\}\cap \{0\} = \{0\}$.